# Is it possible to track 404 answers from server by JS?

Tags: javascript, assets

Sometimes clients requests resources that doesn't exists. We don't know why. Is it possible to track such events by JS (when server returns 404 for `js`, `css`, `png`) files?

Comment: Do you mean: have <img src="" ... > in your html and track with javascript if src load fails?

Comment: something like this + `<script src...>`, `<link href...>`

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you do an Ajax prefetch (jQuery is very handy for that). You just need to catch the click event on every link and do a synchronous ajax call. In the case of a 404 you can provide a proper error message, and if it works, just follow the link.

If the page is properly caught, your server shouldn't have extra work to do.

Answer (score 0):

To track error pages you will need to have the Google Analytics Tracking Code (GATC) added to your error page templates.Without the tracking code on the error pages you will not be able report on these pages or find their associated broken links.Please read more about GATC.I think tracking of such error is not possible by JS.If you found any then please let us know.

Thanks & Regards,
Mainak

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this for images:

```
function preloadImages(data) {

    var newImages = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            newImages[i] = new Image();
            newImages[i].src = data[i];
            console.log(newImages[i].src);
            newImages[i].onload = function() {
                var src = this.src;
                console.log("Succes loading image: " + src);
            };
            newImages[i].onerror = function() {
                var src = this.src;
                console.log("Error loading image: " + src);
            };
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log("Image Loading Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
}

var images = [
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png',
    'unknown.jpg'
];

preloadImages(images);
```

Unfortunately, you still have to know links for all your images and you cant track js and css files with this.

**So you definitely need ajax...**

```
function urlExists(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

and then you need function that will check every possible js, css and png link. Which is easy to make (assume that you want to track only 3 html elements:   and ). 
Since you are not trying to track images called as background-image inside css file, this is much more harder...